# How to mock an Akka Actor to Unit Test a class?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, dependency-injection, akka, akka-testkit

I have a Controller class which controls the requests sent to a Akka actor which is injected in to the controller.

Controller's code:

```
class Controller(actor: ActorRef) {
  def control(msg: String): Future[String] = {
    actor.ask(msg)(Timeout(2 seconds)).mapTo[String]
  }
}
```

And my Actor's code is:

```
class ActorA extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg: String => sender ! msg
    case msg: Int => sender ! msg.toString
    case _ => "Invalid command!"
}
```

Now I need to mock ActorA's behaviour to unit test Controller. Is there a way to do so via Akka TestKit ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a [`TestProbe`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/testkit/TestProbe.html).  From the [testing documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html):

```
val probe = TestProbe()
val future = probe.ref ? "hello"
probe.expectMsg(0 millis, "hello") 
probe.reply("world")
assert(future.isCompleted && future.value == Some(Success("world")))
```

Comment: Thanks @ramon for the response. It explains a lot about **TestProbe()** usage. But can I provide **probe.ref** to Controller and assert result of **control**, I mean something like this:
    `val controller = new Controller(probe.ref);
    val result = Await.result(controller.control("hello"), 2 seconds); assert(result.isCompleted && result.value == Some(Success("world")))`

Comment: @himanshuIIITian You are welcome.  Yes you can use probe.ref in the way you specified, but in your unit testing code after `val probe = TestProbe()` you have to add something like `probe.expectMsg(500 millis, "hello")` and `probe.reply("hello")` so that the probe behave the same way as you expect the Actor to behave.  Happy hacking!

Comment: Hi, @ramon. I tried it the way you specified in previous comment. But, got no success with it as I keep on getting `Timeout Exception` for `val result = Await.result(controller.control("hello"), 2 seconds)`. So, I got it working with `TestActorRef(new ActorA {override def receive: Receive = {case msg:String => sender ! msg ...}})`. I know that we are redefining `receive` for ActorA, but it behaves in the way I want to.

Comment: I suspect it's an ordering problem.  As the docs demonstrate the  `expectMsg` call has to come after the `?` to probe.  But, at least you got something working...