# Playspec Mock actor for unit test

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, akka, actor

Hi I am trying to test this functionality  within the controller, I need to mock "MyActor" for doing the unit test.

```
def populateArraylist[T](hashSet: HashSet[T]): util.ArrayList[T] = {
 val list = new util.ArrayList[T]()
 hashSet.foreach(x => list.add(x))
list
}


@ApiOperation("Get the state of a something”)
def get(ID: String, dateID: String): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async 
{
implicit request =>

(MyShardProvider.shard ? MyActor.EntityPayload(
  Id,
  MySecondActor.GetStateRequest(dateId)))
  .mapTo[GetStateResponse]
  .map(x => {
    Ok(new String(JacksonSerializer.toBytes(new GetResponse(
      x.state.identifier,
      populateArraylist(x.data.transactionList.processedKeys)
    ))))
  })
```

}

Comment: Refer the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265013/how-to-mock-an-akka-actor-to-unit-test-a-class

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to mock the `shard` actor, or else you will have to actually run cluster and sharding when the unit test executes.

Easiest way is probably to either make the `MyShardProvider.shard` something you inject or can override (depending on how you are doing injection in your play app) in the test case to provide the `ActorRef` of a `TestProbe` instead.

That you have `MyShardProvider.shard` at all looks a bit fishy though, you should never have a singleton that contains an actor system, instead you should inject instances as shown in the Play docs here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAkka